# How to write two small equations in the same line?

Tags: equations

I am trying to write equations
`x=a` and `x=b` in the same line.

```
\begin{eqnarray}   

\end{eqnarray}
```

does not provide the solution. Kindly help me.

Comment: `..$x=a$ and $x=b$ ...`

Comment: And what if the equations are long ? like x = max{n/2,l/2} and y = min{n/2,l/2} .

Comment: they may break over the line as the lines in the paragraph are arranged, but that would be a different question since this question explictly asks for two short equations fitting on a line.

Comment: why did you tag this with biblatex?

Comment: ...and why do you  use the outdated `eqnarray` environment?

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: … and (nonetheless) Happy New Year! :o)

Comment: @Bernard: Merci beaucoup! :D

Answer (score 7):

You could use the `align` environment for such purposes.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  x &= a & x &= b \\
  x &=\max(n/2,l/2)  & x &= \min(n/2,l/2) 
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I assume you want the pairs of equations to occupy an entire line and that the amount of whitespace *between* the pair should equal that to the left of the first equation and to the right of the second equation. If this assumption is correct, you could use `\hfill` instructions as is done the following code. (The `\hrule` directives are used merely to illustrate with width of the text block.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\hrule

\bigskip\noindent
$\hfill x=a \hfill x=b \hfill$

\bigskip\noindent
$\hfill x = \max(n/2,l/2) \hfill y = \min(n/2,l/2) \hfill$

\bigskip\hrule
\end{document}
```